# Search problem in ASP.NET Core MVC using Entity Framework as _context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

My project is about hotels and I use SQL Server for the database. I have a problem in my code when I use search to find the hotel by city.

This my code in controller:

```
public IActionResult Index (string city)
{
    var model = _context.hotel
                        .Where(a => a.City.Contains(city)).ToList();
    ViewBag.hotels = model;
    return View(model);
}
```

And this my index page

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="index" method="get">
    <div class="row p-2">
        <div class="col-3">
            <input name="city" type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        @if (ViewBag.hotels != null)
        {
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.hotels as List<Hotel>)
            {
                <tr class="text-center">
                    <td>@item.Id</td>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.Address</td>
                    <td>@item.City</td>
                    <td>@item.Phone</td>
                    <td>@item.Email</td>
                    <td><a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><i class="fa fa-trash text-danger"></i></a></td>
                    <td><a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><i class="fa fa-edit text-success"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
            }
```

I try all but it doesn’t work

Comment: *"it doesn’t work"* - could you be a bit more specific? that `.Where(a => a.City.Contains(city))` may result hotels in "New York" will be listed even though you search for "York."

Comment: Could you share more verbose errors? I test with your code but the function runs correctly.

Comment: Can you share hotel entity properties?